# Why when i refresh the website the list disappear?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, html-lists, refresh, vite

So, im working on a little project of mine, just trying to lear some React + Vite.js and i developed this site where you can save the countries that you visited. I want to make the list stay when you refresh the page but i cant. I tried everything, can someone help me?
This is the code of my App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [newCountry, setNewCountry] = useState('');
  const [newDate, setNewDate] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedCountries = localStorage.getItem('countries');
    if (storedCountries) {
      setCountries(JSON.parse(storedCountries));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('countries', JSON.stringify(countries));
  }, [countries]);

  const handleCountryChange = (e) => {
    setNewCountry(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    setNewDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    if (newCountry && newDate) {
      const newCountryObj = { country: newCountry, date: newDate };
      setCountries((prevCountries) => [...prevCountries, newCountryObj]);
      setNewCountry('');
      setNewDate('');
    }
  };

  const handleEdit = (index) => {
    const updatedCountries = [...countries];
    const editedCountry = updatedCountries[index];
    const newCountryName = prompt(
      'Enter the new country name:',
      editedCountry.country
    );
    if (newCountryName) {
      editedCountry.country = newCountryName;
      setCountries(updatedCountries);
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = (index) => {
    const updatedCountries = [...countries];
    updatedCountries.splice(index, 1);
    setCountries(updatedCountries);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card">
        {/* Form card */}
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="countryInput">País:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="countryInput"
            value={newCountry}
            onChange={handleCountryChange}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="dateInput">Data:</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="dateInput"
            value={newDate}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="button-group">
          <button onClick={handleAdd} className="btn btn-green">
            Adicionar
          </button>
          <button onClick={handleCancel} className="btn btn-red">
            Cancelar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Countries card */}
      {countries.length > 0 && (
        <div className="card">
          {countries.map((country, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="country-item">
              <div className="country-info">
                <span>{country.country}</span>
                <span>{country.date}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="country-actions">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleEdit(index)}
                  className="btn btn-edit"
                >
                  Editar
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleCancel(index)}
                  className="btn btn-red"
                >
                  Apagar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Just want to use localstorage to make my list dont dissapear when i refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the use effect with country as dependency and place the local storage statement in handel submit...
rewrite the code like this like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [newCountry, setNewCountry] = useState("");
    const [newDate, setNewDate] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const storedCountries = localStorage.getItem("countries");
        if (storedCountries) {
            setCountries(JSON.parse(storedCountries));
        }
    }, []);

    const handleCountryChange = (e) => {
        setNewCountry(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleDateChange = (e) => {
        setNewDate(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleAdd = () => {
        if (newCountry && newDate) {
            const newCountryObj = { country: newCountry, date: newDate };
            setCountries((prevCountries) => [...prevCountries, newCountryObj]);
            localStorage.setItem("countries", JSON.stringify(countries));
            setNewCountry("");
            setNewDate("");
        }
    };

    const handleEdit = (index) => {
        const updatedCountries = [...countries];
        const editedCountry = updatedCountries[index];
        const newCountryName = prompt(
            "Enter the new country name:",
            editedCountry.country
        );
        if (newCountryName) {
            editedCountry.country = newCountryName;
            setCountries(updatedCountries);
            localStorage.setItem("countries", JSON.stringify(countries));
        }
    };

    const handleCancel = (index) => {
        const updatedCountries = [...countries];
        updatedCountries.splice(index, 1);
        setCountries(updatedCountries);
        localStorage.setItem("countries", JSON.stringify(countries));
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="card">
                {/* Form card */}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="countryInput">País:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="countryInput"
                        value={newCountry}
                        onChange={handleCountryChange}
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="dateInput">Data:</label>
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        id="dateInput"
                        value={newDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="button-group">
                    <button onClick={handleAdd} className="btn btn-green">
                        Adicionar
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={handleCancel} className="btn btn-red">
                        Cancelar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Countries card */}
            {countries.length > 0 && (
                <div className="card">
                    {countries.map((country, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="country-item">
                            <div className="country-info">
                                <span>{country.country}</span>
                                <span>{country.date}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="country-actions">
                                <button
                                    onClick={() => handleEdit(index)}
                                    className="btn btn-edit"
                                >
                                    Editar
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    onClick={() => handleCancel(index)}
                                    className="btn btn-red"
                                >
                                    Apagar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```